# Is it necessary to double define data type?

Tags: java, android

In the code....

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
```

is it actually necessary to define the data type twice?

Comment: Well, depends on the return type of `getSystemService` ;) But no, there is no type inference in Java.

Comment: @delnan - can you describe what you mean by type interference? - I'm very new to Java with a PHP background

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference. As a simple example, the C# line `var mNotificationManager = getSystemService(ns);` is exactly the same as `<return type of getSystemService(ns)> mNotificationManager = getSystemService(ns);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would argue that you aren't defining it twice, but defining it once, and then casting a value/object to a specific type.  In some cases it is necessary to do this.

My point is there is a difference between definition and casting.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, yes. getSystemService return an Object instance, that you must cast to whatever you need (in this case `NotificationManager`)

Answer (score 0):

No, you should only need to define it once, like:

`NotificationManager mNotificationManager = getSystemService(ns);`

But ensure that `getSystemService` has a return type of `NotificationManager` or one of its sub-classes.

Comment: getSystemService() is an android SDK call and returns type Object.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't declaring the type 2x. in the line,

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(...);
```

You have declared a variable of type NotificationManager nm, and cast the return type of getSystemService(), which is Object, to type NotificationManager, thereby making the assignment to nm legal. Note, you could do this without the cast,

```
Object obj = getSystemService(...);
```

But you can't use obj as anything other an Object unless you cast it.